# how to convert data to mp4 format

Tags: iphone, objective-c

in my apps im able downloaded a short video file from my server using NSURLConnection but the data i received is in data format which cannot be played using MPMoviePlayerViewController. My question is: it is possible to convert NSdata to mp4 file? and how do i play it using MPMoviePlayerViewController. would really appreciate some code snippets cos i'm at a lost. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using `NSURLConnection` to download the data? Just pass the URL to your `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and have it take care of the download. If you have to do the download yourself for some reason you’d have to store the data in a temporary file and pass it’s file URL to the movie player. Or does the server actually provide the video in a format that iOS cannot decode?

Comment: hi sven, thank for your reply. i do not want to stream the video clip. i want to store the data in the apps so i may view it later. it is possible to show some code snippet on how to tore the data in a temporary file and pass it’s file URL to the movie player?

Comment: What format is the NSData data in to begin with?  MP4?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I want to do the same thing. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, i use this code: ([webData writeToFile:filepath  atomically:YES]);

Comment: In the filepath just state the format u want. eg. ...../...../...../video.mp4 the data will be converted to that format in the directory of your app.

Comment: @tan, post the comment on how you got it to work in **Your Answer**.  This way it can help out other people.

Answer (score -1):

Look at AVAssetWriter. This allows you to encode image frames and audio into a MOV or MP4 file using hardware-accelerated methods where possible.